# newman: could not find "htmlextra" reporter ensure that the reporter is installed in the same directory as newman please install reporter using npm

Tags: node.js, api, npm, postman-collection-runner, newman

I did the following to install newman & htmlextra from the node.js command prompt

```
npm install -g newman
npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra
```

After successful installation, from the collection directory i executed the below command from PowerShell

```
newman run sample.postman_collection.json -e Integration.postman_environment.json -r htmlextra
```

& it is working as expected

But when i ran from "C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\bin" with the below command from the PS script

```
node newman run $collectionfilepath -e $environmentfilepath -d $testdatafilepath --disable-unicode -r htmlextra
```

I'm getting error message as newman:

> could not find "htmlextra" reporter ensure that the reporter is installed in the same directory as newman please install reporter using npm

Comment: The reporter wouldn't be in that location though `C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\bin`

Comment: Can you provide me the solution?